# How many songs can I skip on Pandora?

Tags: music, pandora

When I do a "thumbs down" or "I'm tired of this song" in Pandora, it will usually skip to the next song immediately.

If I do this too many times, Pandora says:

> "Unfortunately, our music licenses
>   force us to limit the number of songs
>   you may skip"

- How many times can I skip a song?
- When does the count reset?
- Is there anywhere I can look to see how many skips I have left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Pandora FAQ](http://blog.pandora.com/faq/contents/1525.html)

> There are two types of skip limits:
>
> All Pandora listeners are limited to 6
>   skips per hour, per station.
>
> Listeners to the free Pandora service
>   are limited to 12 total skips per day,
>   across all stations.
>
> NOTE: The hourly limit is based on a
>   rolling sixty-minute interval for each
>   skip. So if you give four skips at
>   12noon, then you give another two
>   skips at 12:30pm, you'll have another
>   four skips available at 1pm-- one hour
>   from the four you gave-- then if you
>   still haven't given any other skips in
>   the meantime, you'll have all six
>   skips back at 1:30pm.
>
> NOTE: The daily limit resets all at
>   once overnight, and is not based on a
>   24-hour interval.24-hour interval.

I don't think you can look up how many skips you've used or have left.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you only get 30 skips on all stations for a 24 hour period on pandora one now.  So, even if you pay, you do not get many more skips, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you subscribe to Pandora One ($36/year), your skips are practically unlimited, because you get six per hour per station, but you can have 99 stations.  (I think Pandora says 100, but it counts the QuickMix as one of your stations.)

So if you get to your six-per-hour limit, you can switch over to another station and you get another six skips there.  (In fact, you'd have to skip a song every six seconds to hit your hourly limit of skips across all 99 stations.)